# Why is casting np.uint8 array to np.float16 array is slower than casting np.uint8 to np.float32 array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I couldn't find any explanation to this, the `ndarray.astype()` returns a new array, so I was expecting it to be faster with np.float16 in comparison to np.float32 to since it allocates less memory. However it takes more than double the time.

```
original_array = np.ones([10,512,1280,3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Here are the results :

```
%%timeit -r 10
float16_array = original_array.astype(np.float16)
```

93.5 ms ± 1.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%%timeit -r 10
float32_array = original_array.astype(np.float32)
```

41.4 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: The type conversion has to convert each value; that is much more expensive than allocating a single chunk of memory. Loosing a factor of 2 for allocation is insignificant versus having hardware support for 32bit float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CPU probably has an instruction that numpy can use to do the uint8->float32 conversion (for instance on x86, `CVTDQ2PS` in SSE2/AVX/AVX512 would work to do between four and sixteen conversions in a single instruction), but doesn't have an equivalent instruction for float16. Half-precision float support is relatively sparse outside of GPUs.